# How to easily configure multiple u-boot variables

Tags: environment-variables, u-boot

I need to change multiple u-boot environment variables every time I setup a new embedded device e.g. ip address, ethernet address, etc.
Typing at the terminal prompt is tedious, and, I don't know if it's my terminal, buy trying to cut and paste anything more than a few characters can result in errors. Changing them in a text editor and copying that file to a specific location in flash would be much better than the terminal.
Anyone have a good way to change multiple environment variables at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script file is ideal for this situation.  Its much better than copy & pasting for many commands and can handle much more complexity.  You can enter all your commands into a text file and [create a script image using `mkimage`](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootScripts) (where `myscript` is the text file's name):

```
mkimage -T script -C none -n 'My Script' -d myscript myscript.img
```

Then you can simply load and execute `myscript.img` to perform all setup tasks for the device.

For example, to load and execute `myscript.img` from USB stick:

```
usb start && load usb 0:1 ${loadaddr} myscript.img && source ${loadaddr}
```

It is possible to add this load command to U-Boot's default environment so all you need to do is run the name of the command.  You can even add logic to the default boot sequence to automatically perform the device setup if the USB device and script file are present.  Depending on the U-Boot version, you can manipulate the default environment by either modifying the U-Boot source or by [editing uEnv.txt (when supported)](http://linux-sunxi.org/UEnv.txt).

Scripts are also useful for maintaining multiple setup configurations that would allow you to set the device up for one of many deployment or development configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to copy and paste my variables into U-Boot. You can separate the declarations by semicolons to if you want to do all of the variables at once, like this:

```
    setenv ipaddr 192.168.1.5; setenv serverip 192.168.1.10;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't realize you could put more than one setenv on a line like that. I've tried PuTTY and TeraTerm.  In both cases if I copy and paste more than a few characters I start to see dropped characters. It's probably because I'm going out a serial port to an embedded device at a fairly slow 38400 baud rate.

Comment: How areally you pasting from your clipboard in PuTTY? Right clicking? I've been able to do it at a baud of 115200, havent tried a device slower than that.